# possible values for @CucumberOptions(plugin = ...)

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-junit, test-reporting

I am using @CucumberOptions(plugin = {"pretty"} for test report in cucumber but the default colors for this are really bad..so I am looking to change the font color in output report. Anyone as any idea..how  proceed further?

Answer (score 2):

For console colors see [Console-Colours](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Console-Colours).

For reports you can specify that the report be output in JSON and then pass the generated JSON to a custom formatter.  See [Custom-Formatters](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Custom-Formatters).  BTW, this is how TeamCity creates its reports.

Here is an example of generating both HTML and JSON reports:

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@Options(format = { "html:target/cucumber-html-reports", "json:target/cucumber-html-reports/cucumber.json"},
    features = { "."},
    tags = {"~@obsolete", "~@wip", "~@detailed", "~@SP", "@FRA001, @SWZ001"},
    strict = true)

public class CucumberRunnerTest {
}
```

JSON cucumber-jvm reports are not intended to be readable but to be intermediates that you pass to other applications. See the individual custom formatters for color options that they support.