# How to find the possible values for CucumberOptions (plugin = ...)

Tags: java, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, intellij-plugin, cucumber-java

I found another similarly titled question here, [42878832](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42878832/possible-values-for-cucumberoptionsplugin), but it didn't answer my question.

I am running Cucumber and would like to customise my TestRunner by specifying `CucumberOptions`. I am trying to add values to the `plugin` option and am following an example where it's specified a value of `progress` as one of the allowed values. When I run my code I don't see it producing the expected output `.P-` so am thinking that perhaps the version I am using today doesn't support this feature anymore. I am using Intellij (2020.2), Java (15), cucumber-java (6.8.1).

Does anyone know where the options are documented and more specifically where can I read the list of available options for the `plugin` option. I found this page [CucumberOptions docs](https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/api/) on the Cucumber site but it wasn't very helpful.

My TestRunner class looks like below.

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class) @CucumberOptions(
        features = {"cucumber/features"},
        glue = {"steps"},
        plugin = {"progress", "pretty", "html:Report1"},
        dryRun = false,
        monochrome = true
        //tags = {"@P1"}
        //name = {"Logo"}
        ) public class TestRunner { }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the listed options in [here](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/main/junit-platform-engine/src/main/java/io/cucumber/junit/platform/engine/Constants.java)

In javadoc:

look [here](https://javadoc.io/doc/io.cucumber/cucumber-junit/latest/io/cucumber/junit/CucumberOptions.html#plugin())

If you want to have an idea , how some of them works, have a look [here](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/extended-reports-bddcucumber-meghana-reddy/)

Here is a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52093885/how-to-write-cucumberoptions-as-format-htmlfolderpath-in-new-version-of-cucu) that says about how to use `progress`

Comment: thank you - this is helpful - but I dont see any documentation or examples of the progress option which I was looking for in the question - do you know where I might find this please ?

Comment: @robbie70 Edited above with more info